# HTML Button with CSS

Tags: html

I have this CSS for a button-

```
a.button {
   border-top: 1px solid #7f93bc;
   background: #7f93bc;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7f93bc), to(#7f93bc));
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7f93bc, #7f93bc);
   padding: 10.5px 21px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
   -moz-border-radius: 0px;
   border-radius: 0px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
a.button:hover {
   border-top-color: #0e1f5b;
   background: #0e1f5b;
   color: #ffffff;
    }
a.button:active {
   border-top-color: #0e1f5b;
   background: #0e1f5b;
   }
```

The below turns out a link. I want to make it turn out a button in the above style. What can I replace the below with?

```
$theOffers .= "<br><li class=\"gateway-offer\"><a href=\"http://fakeurlforanon/aff_c?offer_id=".$offer['id']."&aff_id=$affiliateId\" target=\"_blank\">$offer[name]</a></li><br>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the class to the  tag:

```
...ffer\"><a class=\"button\" href=\"http://fakeurlf...
```

Comment: You'll need to add a demo.  You have 3 responses, all substantively the same... so you've got some other issue somewhere else.

Comment: Um..  Looks the way I would expect it to here.  Just like a facebook button, right?

Comment: It's loading right in chrome, displaying a link in firefox, and showing a blue bar in IE. Had to remove the button code for the time being... its currently in live use and need IE traffic.

Comment: I just tested it in FF (added the button class through FireBug) and it looked correct there.  You might have to flush your cache if you just adding the class into your stylesheet.

Comment: Will try that. Now with IE, I can hover over the button but the button wont initially display no matter what color it is.

Comment: Yea, its working in FF too. IE just isnt displaying it until you hover over. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it working. Had to change the way the background was set in the css. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to add `class="button"` to your anchor tag, like so:

```
$theOffers .= "<br><li class=\"gateway-offer\"><a class=\"button\" href=\"http://fakeurlforanon/aff_c?offer_id=".$offer['id']."&aff_id=$affiliateId\" target=\"_blank\">$offer[name]</a></li><br>";
```

That should make it pick up all the button styling you already have.

Comment: This caused the entire page to not load.

Comment: Oops - I forgot to escape the quotes around the button tag. Updated now.

Comment: hmm still loaded a link. Must be conflicting with something else on the page. Thanks for your efforts =)

Comment: The 'You Won' button appears like a button to me  dark blue background with white text. The styles from your original post are being applied correctly, too. Caching problem at your end, maybe?

Comment: Got it working in Chrome and FF. IE just isnt displaying until you hover over it.

Comment: Got it working. Had to change the way the background was set in the css. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually specify that the `<a>` should be of class `button`.

```
$theOffers .= '
<br />
<li class="gateway-offer">
    <a class="button" href="http://fakeurlforanon/aff_c?offer_id=' . $offer["id"] . '&amp;aff_id=' . $affiliateId. '" target="_blank">' . $offer["name"] . '</a>
</li><br />';
```